# How to pass an array to another page with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parameter-passing

I have an array which looks like:

```
$diseases= [
            ['letter' => 'A' , 'options' => "<div ..."],
            ....
           ];
```

And I pass the letter as a parameter in the URL. It works. But I can't understand how to make it print the options that correspond to the letter on the page. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you want to pass this whole array as a query string? Or you have this array on the page but based on letter present in query string you want to print its corresponding option?

Comment: What u have tried

Comment: Can you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in the session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['array_name'] = $array_name;
```

Or if you want to send it via a form you can serialize it:

```
<input type='hidden' name='input_name' value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($array_name)); ?>" />

$passed_array = unserialize($_POST['input_name']);
```

Comment: Never *ever* print serialize output for clients. It can print unwanted information.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$diseases = [
  'A' => "<div>A</div>",
  'B' => "<div>B</div>",
];

$letterAction = isset($_GET['letterAction']) ? $_GET['letterAction'] : ''; //if the letterAction parameter is defined in the URL, then get it's value

if (isset($diseases[$letterAction])) {
//if the letterAction is available in the array, then print it's value 
//i.e. isset($diseases["A"]) would return true but isset($diseases["C"]) would return false in this case
  echo $diseases[$letterAction];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to store information to be used on all pages:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['diseases'] = $diseases; // store information to key data
```

On the other pages you use:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['diseases']);
```

If you only want the data to be set for 1 specific page you can use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php%60)

```
$diseases = ['diseases' => $diseases];
$str = http_build_query($diseases);

echo "<a href='yourpage.php?$str'>click</a>";
```

Now on the next page you simply use:

```
parse_str($_GET['diseases'], $diseases);

print_r($diseases);
```